# How to keep the scroll position of a div which is updated via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a chat module. I am using the `setInterval()` function to fetch chat history.

I have a scroll bar (shown after the send/receive operation) and then whenever I get a result from the database via AJAX then
the scroll bar should stay in the same position, however right now the scroll bar is going to the top of the messages.

How can I handle the AJAX response an keep the message list in a specific position?

```js
var scrollTopPosition = $("div#chat_sc_in").scrollTop();
var scroll_l = $("div#chat_sc_in").scrollLeft();
alert('Height is ' + scrollTopPosition);
alert('Width is ' + scroll_l);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "<?php echo base_url('Welcome/user_chat_fetch'); ?>",
  data: '',
  success: function(html) {
    $('.user_chat_module').html(html);
    $('.user_chat_module').scrollTop(scrollTopPosition);
  }
});
```

Comment: If you `append()` to the `.user_chat_module` you get this behaviour by default. The problem is because you are destroying the original content then recreating it. Can you amend your PHP to only return the new messages? Better yet, don't use AJAX polling at all for a chat system as it has ***a lot*** of problems. Use websockets instead.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollTop will remain constant after even the height of div increases. The solution is to track the distance between the scrollTop and the bottom of the div when ever the user scrolls and assign the difference of the new height and the calculated value when new content get added.

```
<script>
     var scrollDifference = 0;
     $("div#chat_sc_in").scroll(event => {
          scrollDifference = event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop;
     });

     $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:"<?php echo base_url('Welcome/user_chat_fetch'); ?>",
           data:'',
           success:function(html){
                $('.user_chat_module').html(html);
                var divThatHasScrollBar = $("div#chat_sc_in")[0];
                divThatHasScrollBar.scrollTop = divThatHasScrollBar.scrollHeight - scrollDifference;
           }}); 
</script>
```